# Python 3.5s - How to separate scraped paragraph text with new lines

Tags: python, text, newline, block, spaces

I am scraping text from a website and exporting it into a notepad document. I am trying to separate paragraphs, tried all possible combinations of print + '\n' but nothing works. I wonder what I am doing wrong, for I only get one big block of text imported into the notepad document. I am a newbie so would be great if you explain the mistake I am doing, not just provide a solution. Thank you! PS- Also, I thought I would have to use "outfile.close()" after the extracting operation, but if I do the script does not work...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, re

req = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
req.addheaders = [ ('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0') ]

title = soup.title.text

body = soup.find_all('p')
outfile = open("wiki_test.txt","wb")
for i in body:
    print(i.text)
    outfile.write(bytes(i.text+'\n'+"###############", 'UTF-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in to readability. For this code though try

```
with open("wiki_test.txt","wb") as outfile:
    for i in body:
        print(i.text + '\n')
        outfile.write(bytes(i.text+'\n'+"###############", 'UTF-8'))
```

Comment: I get the exact same result using this code. I am starting to wonder if there is something wrong with Notepad or Windows 8, but that would be very unusual, woudn't it? On the pycharm output console  I see the text properly formatted with the lines in between paragraphs, but then the output to file is still without new lines, even with your code.

Comment: Could it be something I don't know about the UTF-8 encoding thing?